# Improving the performance of this search?

Tags: c++

Is there way to do the following search using a faster way? The items on A array are sorted in DESC order.

```
int find_pos(int A[], int value, int items_no, bool only_exact_match)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < items_no; i++)
        if(value == A[i] || (value > A[i] && !only_exact_match))
            return i;

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: `std::lower_bound` algorithm.

Comment: Could you describe, in plain terms, what the logic is behind the search?  It seems one behavior is to search for an exact match, but the other behavior is a bit fuzzy to me.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen The other behavior is "if an exact match is not found then return the closest item to value that is less than value"

Comment: You could use a divide and conquer approach for the first part of your search.  This would reduce `O(n)` to `O(lgn)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A binary search

```
int left = 0;
int right = items_no; // Exclusive
while (left < right) {
    int mid = (left + right) / 2;

    if (value == A[mid])
        return mid;
    if (value < A[mid]) {
        left = mid + 1;
    } else {
        right = mid;
    }
}
return only_exact_match ? -1 : right - 1; // The greater
```

Comment: @Holt I return mid if an exact match was found inside the loop.

Comment: @JoopEggen Sorry, missed that.

Comment: @MATH000 left (or right) should be the insert position, hence the index of the next smaller value. One less either the next larger value or -1 at the beginning. Is the array indeed fully ordered descendingly? But maybe I am getting old.

Comment: @Joop Eggen No, you are not getting old :)

Comment: @Joop Eggen The only issue is that in the end it should return right not right -1

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`std::lower_bound`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/?kw=lower_bound) algorithm in your case. It performs binary search with O(log N), as other people wrote. It will be something like this:

```
int find_pos(int A[], int value, int items_no, bool only_exact_match)
{
    const int *pos_ptr = std::lower_bound(A, A + items_no, value, std::greater<int>());
    const ptrdiff_t pos = pos_ptr - A;

    if (pos >= items_no)
        return -1;
    if (*pos_ptr != value && only_exact_match)
        return -1;
    return pos;
}
```

Comment: Small remark: `std::greater()` is not valid, you need `std::greater<>()` (c++14 and above) or `std::greater<int>()` (c++11 and below).

Comment: Yes, it needs a template argument. Honestly I didn't compile this code. It is approximately what is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Because your array is sorted, you can search in steps, akin to a bisection. First, check the midpoint against your value. If it's equal, you have your answer. If it's greater, your value is in the lower half of the array. If not, your value is on the upper half. Repeat this process by bisecting the remaining elements of the array until you find your value, or run out of elements. As for your second if clause, if no matching value is found, the closest smaller element is element i+1, if that exists (i.e. you are not at the end of the array).